# If $\| v \| = \| T(v) \|$ for all $v \in V$, then $T$ is onto.

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $V$ is finite dimensional. $T: V \rightarrow V$ is linear.

I know that if  $\| v \| = \| T(v) \|$  for all $v \in V$ then $T$ is unitary. That is, $\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$. I also know that to show $T$ is onto, it suffices to show that $T$ is one-to-one. Here's what I did:

Suppose there exists $x$ and $y$ such that $Tx=Ty=\lambda$ and $x \neq y$. Then $\langle Tx,Ty\rangle =\langle x,y\rangle =\langle \lambda,\lambda\rangle$. Then $\langle x-\lambda,y-\lambda\rangle =0$.

Then it follows that $x-\lambda=0$ or $y-\lambda=0$. But then either way we have $x=y=\lambda$. Thus $T$ is one-to-one and therefore onto.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: $\langle x, y\rangle = \langle \lambda, \lambda\rangle$ does not imply $\langle x-\lambda, y-\lambda\rangle = 0$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's see that $\ker T = \{0\}$. Let $x \in \ker T$. So $Tx = 0$, and: $$\|x\| = \|Tx\| = 0 \implies x = 0. $$ So $T$ is injective. Since $V$ has finite dimension, $T$ is onto.

Comment: Thank you! This is very neat!

Comment: @Zikai Is there anything else we can help you with? If the problem is solved, one thing you can do is tick the green checkmark at the left to accept the answer - this way the question goes out of the unanswered queue, and organizes the site better.

Comment: I checked it. Thanks! : )